# How to install Windows 7 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS using WINE

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, wine, windows-7

I want to install windows 7 home premium on my ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I already have a windows 7 home premium setup .exe, I am using WINE to run it.
When I execute it it shows "Windows was unable to create an installation folder error code 0x8007007A". 
So I used GParted to create a new partition of size 30 GB and changed the file system to NTFS and selected for boot flag and then I started the setup again, but it made no difference. I dont know what to do next. Please help!

Comment: Wine is for installing some Windows programs, not the entire OS. Either do a dual boot or use a virtual machine if your hardware is capable enough.

Comment: You can't install Windows on Wine, just as you can't install Windows on Windows.

Comment: how to do a dual boot? I have the setup file on a usb. I havn't got the installation CD

Comment: See [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](/q/6317/175814)

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to quote something first.

> To overcome this weakness, a compatibility layer called WINE was created. The name originally stood for Wine Is Not an Emulator (because everyone mistook the tool for a Windows emulator). The name is now simply Wine. Effectively, what Wine did was to allow Windows applications to run on the Linux platform. -- Linux.com

So, I think it's not possible to do what you are trying to do. But there are other alternatives to use windows on top of Ubuntu.

- You can try `virtualbox` or `vmware` or any other virtualization softwares available for debian based operating systems.
- Or, you can try to create a partition and then install windows over it. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu).